# Why does shuffling sequences of data in tf.keras.dataset affect the order of sequences differently between tf.fit and tf.predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, shuffle

I am training an LSTM deep learning model with time series sequences and labels.

I generate a tensorflow dataset "train_data" and "test_data"

```
train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
data=data,
targets=None,
sequence_length=total_window_size,
sequence_stride=1,
batch_size=batch_size,
shuffle=is_shuffle).map(split_window).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

I then train the model with the above datasets

```
model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, validation_data = test_data, callbacks=callbacks)
```

And then run predictions to obtain the predicted values

```
train_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in train_data], axis=0)
train_predictions = model.predict(train_data)
test_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in test_data], axis=0)
test_predictions = model.predict(test_data)
```

Here is my question: When I plot the train/test label data against the predicted values I get the following plot when I do **not** shuffle the sequences in the dataset building step:

[image]

Here the output **with** shuffling:

[image]

**Question** Why is this the case? I use the exact same source dataset for training and prediction. The dataset should be shuffled. Is there a chance that TensorFlow shuffles the data twice randomly, once during training and another time for predictions? I tried to supply a shuffle seed but that did not change things either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset gets shuffled everytime you iterate through it. What you get after your list comprehension isn't in the same order as when you write `predict`. If you don't want that, pass:

```
shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, this explains it well and provides a solution. But I guess you meant to set the flag to false to prevent reshuffling each iteration...

Comment: Yes, indeed. Apologies for my confusion.